Excel - multiple IF conditions
I am trying to write a formula or function which looks for certain key words in one column and based on keywords, assign owners in another column.
Something like
If G4 contains switch or router or dir or cable then owner is Mike, If G4 contains server or chassis then owner is Mabel, If G4 contains bike or car or van then owner is Martha, else owner is Melvin
I tried this but no it keeps resulting Mike for cells, I tried putting OR as multiple FIND but it kept erroring
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("switch",G4)), IF(ISERROR(FIND("Server",G4)), "Mike", "Mabel"), "Melvin)"

Tried ISERROR and FIND, see original comment.

It might be useful to show us some sample data and the expected outcome.

Please post some sample data. It would be helpful to post answers!

Hard to know without seeing data samples with expected output. But frequently, complicated IF statements can be simplified by using tables.
Here is a formula that does what you describe, and the tables are hard-coded in the formula, but you can easily set up tables on your worksheet.
I used SEARCH instead of FIND for case-insensitivity.
=IFERROR(
    INDEX(
        {
            "Mike";
            "Mike";
            "Mike";
            "Mike";
            "Mabel";
            "Mabel";
            "Martha";
            "Martha";
            "Martha"
        },
        XMATCH(
            TRUE,
            ISNUMBER(
                SEARCH(
                    {
                        "switch";
                        "router";
                        "dir";
                        "cable";
                        "server";
                        "chassis";
                        "bike";
                        "car";
                        "van"
                    },
                    G4
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    "Melvin"
)


It's the rightmost way. More, it necessary to put the item/owner table into the worksheet for easy maintenance.

@rotabor Yes, that's what I would do, and I am sure the OP can also set up a table on his worksheet if this answer works out for him.

You should try SWITCH instead:
=SWITCH(TRUE(),
cell=condition,result,
cell=condition2,result2, etc)

or
=SWITCH(
cell_address,
condition,result,
condition2,result2,
etc..)


Thanks for the fun 'assignment' :)
XLOOKUP with wildcard
This short version may be sufficient:
=XLOOKUP("*" & G2:G6 & "*", B3:B5, A3:A5, A2, 2)



MMULT for fun
It may be easier if you create a small table with owner and items details.

Enter items to assign in $G$2:$G$6, expand the range as needed
MMULT is used to get the index for the matching row
XLOOKUP returns the owner for the first match
You can change the last line (VSTACK) to other variables to see the result of the variables or steps.

=LET(
    default_owner, $A$2,
    item_col, $B$3:INDEX($B$3:$B$100, COUNTA($B$3:$B$100)),
    owner_col, $A$3:INDEX($A$3:$A$100, COUNTA($A$3:$A$100)),
    items_to_assign, $G$2:$G$6,
    delim, ",",
    cols_per_row, LEN(item_col) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(item_col, delim, )) +
        1,
    col_indices, SEQUENCE(, MAX(cols_per_row)),
    items_expanded, IFNA(
        TRIM(
            TEXTBEFORE(
                TEXTAFTER(
                    delim & item_col & delim,
                    delim,
                    col_indices
                ),
                delim
            )
        ),
        ""
    ),
    assign_item, LAMBDA(item,
        LET(
            item_matched, MMULT(
                --(items_expanded = TRIM(item)),
                SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(items_expanded), , 1, 0)
            ),
            XLOOKUP(1, item_matched, owner_col, default_owner)
        )
    ),
    VSTACK("Owner", MAP(items_to_assign, assign_item))
)


